# Send POST request to asp.net mvc action via Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, fiddler

I have an `ASP.NET MVC` web site. One of my routes is a `URL` that takes 5 parameters. For the sake of illustration, these parameters are named `parameter1`, `parameter2`, `parameter3`, `parameter4`, and `parameter5`. Currently, I'm constructing a URL in some `C#` code that will `POST` to the mvc action via a `WebClient`. that code looks like this:

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.UploadStringCompleted += myWebClient_UploadStringCompleted;

string url = "http://www.example.com/customer/" + parameter1 + "/orders/" + parameter2 + "/" + parameter3 + "/" + parameter4 + "/" + parameter5;
myWebClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
```

I'm confident that the `UploadString` method does a `POST`. I need to do a `POST`, because my parameter values can be very long. In fact, I estimate that occasionally, the total url length may be 20000 characters long. Regardless, I get a `400 error` when I attempt to post my data. In an effort to debug this, I'm  trying to figure out how to simulate a `POST` in `Fiddler`.

Assuming that I am passing values via a query string as shown above, what values do I enter into `Fiddler`? From the `Composer` tab, I'm not sure what to enter for the `Request Headers` area. I'm also not entirely sure what to enter for the url. I'm not sure if I put the entire URL in there, including the parameter values, or if those belong in the `Request Headers`.

What I need to enter into `Fiddler`, so that I can debug my issue?

Comment: why not write a tiny c# client that POSTS to it? Though I only know the basics of Fiddler

Comment: There's no such overload of `UploadStringAsync` as what you have shown in your question. Where are you passing the actual payload of this POST request? Also you seem to have mentioned some query string parameters in your question, but there aren't any such parameters. Your parameters seem to be passed as part of the path portion of the url.

Comment: _"In an effort to debug this, I'm trying to figure out how to simulate a POST in Fiddler."_ - you can also just let the server log the error and inspect that. Or inspect the request that your application makes.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Basically all your parameters are a part of the URL, and this is the root of your problem. Here is what is going on: you are hitting the URL length limitation, and receiving a "400 Bad request" error. In real world most web browsers do not work with URLs more than 2000 characters long.

To resolve this problem I would suggest doing a bit of refactoring, so that request is posted to the URL `http://www.example.com/customer/parameter1/orders` or even `http://www.example.com/customer/orders` with parameters send in request body. Here is how test such request in Fiddler:

1. On `Composer` tab choose `POST` request verb
2. Specify the URL as

   http://www.example.com/customer/parameter1/orders

   or

   http://www.example.com/customer/orders
3. In `Request Headers` section you can set content type header like

   ```
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   ```

   or any other header you might require. Or just leave it blank which will work in your case.
4. Finally in `Request Body` field list your parameters in query string form

   ```
   parameter1name=parameter1value&parameter2name=parameter2value
   ```

In this new case here is how you can send such a request using `WebClient`:

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.UploadStringCompleted += myWebClient_UploadStringCompleted;

string url = "http://www.example.com/customer/orders";
string data = "parameter1name=parameter1value&parameter2name=parameter2value";

myWebClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), data);
```

Comment: Then how do I update my WebClient code to pass along this information in the format you're showing?

Comment: @EelsFan, `WebClient.UploadStringAsync` has an overload that accepts parameters in query string form. Please see update.

Comment: I see the update, now I'm wondering if i need to update my route though. My route is currently             routes.MapRoute(
                name: "OrderInfo",
                url: "customer/{parameter1}/orders/{parameter2}/{parameter3}/{parameter4}/{parameter5}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "CustomerOrder" }
            );

Comment: @EelsFan, yes, it needs some updates as well. Remove parameters from it as they are no longer part of the url. But leave them as parameters of action method - ASP.NET MVC still is able to map request body to action params.

Comment: And don't forget to change HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 6):

I simply mimic the exact request that was sent.

This is how I do it:

1. Open Fiddler
2. Go to the page that I want to re-issue the command i.e. repeat the bug step but watch for the request in the list
3. Select it from the list and right-click, go to replay > reissue and edit
4. This build a replicated request but hits a break point before it is sent (You will see the red bar on the right)
5. Above this you can edit the values that were sent by double-clicking on any of them in Headers, QueryString etc
6. Then hit Run to Complete