# Post passing null model value and how to properly removed or fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Sample output when button is submitted,

[image]

[image]

I don't know why i have null value, here is my sample form. the details from it is from a partial view

[image]

Partial view code

```
        @model SimplyAccounting.Models.TransactionViewModels.JournalDetailsViewModel
        @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("JournalDetailsViewModel"))
        {
            <tr class="checkDetails" id="@Model.Guid">
                <td>

        //code here
    <td>
<tr class="DocumentDetails" id="@Model.Guid">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btnModal" guid="@Model.Guid"><i class="far fa-file"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="delete" name="delete" value="delete" onclick="javascript: deleteBook(document.getElementById('@Model.Guid'))"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                </div>
            </td>
</tr>
        }
```

I notice, null value will show if I added new row and remove it. If I add 2 rows more, and remove 2 rows, 2 null values also shows

Code in adding row

```
function GetRow() {
        var form = $('form');
        var urlStr = '@Url.Action("CreateJournalDetails", "Journals")';
        $.ajax({
            url: urlStr,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#journalRow').append('<tr>' + data + '</tr>');
                $('tbody#journalRow>tr.checkDetails').appendTo('#checkRow');
                form.data('validator', null);
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            }
        });
    }
```

Code for removing row:

```
function deleteBook(bookDiv) {
        var id = $(bookDiv).attr("id");
        var cnt = document.getElementsByClassName("DocumentDetails").length;
        if (cnt > 2) {
            bookDiv.remove();
            document.getElementById(id).remove();
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult CreateJournalDetails(JournalDetailsViewModel vmodel)
    {
        vmodel = new JournalDetailsViewModel();
        vmodel.Gla_List = GlaList();
        vmodel.Function_List = FunctionList();
        vmodel.Expense_List = ExpenseList();
        vmodel.Bank_List = BankList();
        vmodel.Location_List = LocationList();
        vmodel.Branch_List = BranchList();
        vmodel.Asset_List = AssetList();
        vmodel.Item_List = ItemList();

        return PartialView("_JournalDetails", vmodel);
    }
```

Comment: is it because you are mapping to a list that has the null in it?  you go to the trouble of checking for nulls but do not use that object to map against

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now when you are server side, you can just remove the null items from your view model into a new list and add the new list to your context.

You should always assume that data from the post can be wrong/manipulated and you should as much as possible verify the data you are getting in your post. So even if you fix it in the frontend you should make sure that the data you get back is valid.

That said, this here should fix your problem.

```
var newViewModel = new List<JournalDetails>();
foreach (var item in newViewModel.JournalDetailsViewModel)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        ...
        newViewModel.Add(item);
    }
}

var dtails = _mapper.Map<List<JournalDetails>>(newViewModel.JournalDetailsViewModel);
_context.AddRange(newViewModel);

...
```

Comment: thanks this solved the issue but i want to also know how to fix the client side

Comment: When I fix that kind of problems I use Fiddler and look at the actual values that are posted from the browser and usually there is some leftovers that you have forgotten to delete on the client side.

Comment: You can look at the answers in this question to help you set up Fiddler for asp.net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215523/send-post-request-to-asp-net-mvc-action-via-fiddler#17215973